# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string on my project

Tags: python, mysql

Please help. My code for insertion of data to a database returns with an error message:

> `insertVar =("INSERT INTO %a ( ticker, date, openPrice, dayHigh, dayLow, closePrice, volume ) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" %(stripedTicker))`
>
> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string.

The code is

```
def insertData (data):
    insertVar =("INSERT INTO %a ( ticker, date, openPrice, dayHigh, dayLow, closePrice, volume ) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" %(stripedTicker))
    cur.execute(insertVar, data)
    conn.commit()
```

The variable `data = ['Access Bank Plc', '2018-12-15', '7.45', '7.50', '7.45', '7.45', '18,152,221']`
Any help on how to resolve this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In your string you want to insert 8 strings, but your list only has 7 elements

Comment: What I have is 7 strings ( ticker, date, openPrice, dayHigh, dayLow, closePrice, volume ), and that is what I want insert. I intentionally skipped my id column as is auto_increment.

Comment: Please, assist show me the 8 strings. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The error is informing you that your `insertVar` variable is expecting 8 arguments from `stripedTicker`. I'm guessing your `stripedTicker` variable only contains one argument to format `%a`. (And you want to keep the `%s`'s to be formatted by `cur.execute()`.)

For example, this would work

```
print('%s %s' % ('a', 'b')) # prints 'a b'
```

but the following wouldn't

```
print('%s %s' % ('a')) # TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

since the `%` formatter expects arguments to fill each `%s`. Your current way of formatting the string won't work unless you add extra percentage signs (`%`) at the front of your `%s` arguments. For example

```
print('%s %%s' % ('a')) # prints 'a %s'
```

Thus, adding extra `%` to your `%s`'s...

```
insertVar = ("INSERT INTO %a ( ticker, date, openPrice, dayHigh, dayLow, closePrice, volume ) \  
    VALUES ( %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s)" % (stripedTicker))
```

**or** opt for another way of formatting, for example, using f-strings:

```
insertVar = f"INSERT INTO {stripedTicker} ( ticker, date, openPrice, dayHigh, dayLow, closePrice, volume ) \  
    VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

or `.format()`

```
insertVar = "INSERT INTO {} ( ticker, date, openPrice, dayHigh, dayLow, closePrice, volume ) \  
    VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)".format(stripedTicker)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a million times, TrebuchetMS. Your solution worked fine. Thanks. I'm very grateful.